# How to feed back LSTM output to input in pytorch dataloader

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, video-processing, dataloader

I’m doing video prediction frame prediction using LSTM. How do I implement this in my custom dataloader?

Answer (score 0):

Andreas Holm Nielsen has put up a good guide on this subject

https://holmdk.github.io/2020/04/02/video_prediction.html

https://github.com/holmdk/Video-Prediction-using-PyTorch